# Config stylelint in react tsx using MUI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, eslint, stylelint

I got a project using:

- mui
- typescript
- react

I want to configure stylelint to check for HEX colors used in tsx files

current config:

```
"stylelint": {
  "rules": {
    "color-no-hex": true
  }
}
```

running it:
`npx stylelint "**/*.tsx"`

this blows up after finding `imports`

```
src/components/Page.tsx
 2:10  ✖  Unknown word  CssSyntaxError // this is an import
```

this is an example of what I want linted:

```
<Typography color="#FFFFFF99">text</Typography>
<Box sx={{bgcolor: "#FFFFFF"}}/>
```

So the question/s:

- Can this be done with stylelint, how to config?
- Can this be done with another linter, how to config?

Comment: Have you ever resolved this?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik I have not found a solution.